# Diagonalize the Pauli Matrices $X$ and $Y$. Check if $Y$ is diagonal in the basis formed by the eigenvectors of $X$ and vice versa

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information

please any expertise gives me an answer to this question. I had my exam on this.

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X will be diagonal relative to a basis that consists of its eigenvectors (side question - how do we know it’s eigenvectors are orthogonal to one another ?). If Y is diagonal relative to the same basis then X and Y will commute relative to that basis. And if X and Y commute relative to one basis then they commute relative to all bases (can you prove this ?). In other words, commutativity is a property of the operators X and Y, not just of how they happen to be expressed.

So ... do X and Y commute ?